# SQL keeps throwing "missing left parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't understand what I am doing here but I keep getting a "missing left parenthesis" error in the following SQL code. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Newbie here.

```
CREATE TABLE AGENT_INFO
    (AgentID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY, AgentName VARCHAR, PhoneNumber VARCHAR);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6

Answer (score 0):

`varchar` datatype requires *size*:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE AGENT_INFO
  2      (AgentID     SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  3       AgentName   VARCHAR2(20),
  4       PhoneNumber VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
```

(Note that Oracle recommends `varchar2` instead of `varchar`.)

Comment: Apparently, there's already table/object whose name is AGENT_INFO. As you can't have two objects with the same name, you'll have to either rename this table, or drop object with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The `VARCHAR` data type needs a size (and should probably be `VARCHAR2` in Oracle and [`SMALLINT` is an alias](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) for `NUMBER(38)`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE AGENT_INFO(
  AgentID     SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  AgentName   VARCHAR2(10),
  PhoneNumber VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

If you want a string column that can accept text without specifying a maximum size then use `CLOB`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AGENT_INFO(
  AgentID     NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
  AgentName   CLOB,
  PhoneNumber CLOB
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5403dd90083715233b9dfc1c52b83d8e)*